# Play several MP3 sounds Simultaneously

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, avaudioplayer

Is it possible to play several MP3 sounds Simultaneously with AVAudioPlayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but note that there is only one (known) hardware MP3 decoder on current devices, any other simultaneous sounds must be decoded in software by the AV player.  So you will eventually run out of CPU cycles to keep up with over some (device dependent) number of sounds.

Comment: At this time i can't do it please help me how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It says so in the documentation.